# Comparing two values set in MySQL table php

Tags: php, mysql, database-schema

I have a mysql table that has 2 columns, claim_status and show (both VARCHAR(500)) I tested with int didn't work.

I want to query only the items that have claim_status='0' and show='1'

right now nothing is returned here is my PHP code:

```
$query  = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName WHERE claim_status='0' AND show='1'";
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE claim_status='0' AND show='1'";
```

** it fails on this line **
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName WHERE claim_status=0 AND show=1";

Comment: Are you running those queries at all?

Comment: "...FROM $tableName AND claim_stat..." I presume the "AND" there is a typo?

Comment: yes i am running the queries, Pete what could the typo be?

Comment: @user2127136 You need to write `WHERE` first then a value or condition before you write `AND`

Comment: yeah I saw that changed it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE claim_status='0' AND show='1'; 
    $result =  mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show=1' at line 1

i got this message

Comment: Prince you have the right idea i dont know whats wrong with my sql query

Comment: [`show`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is a reserved word in MySQL. If you have a column named that and want to select from that, you should use `\`show\``

Comment: Not a problem! This question may be closed for being to vague or specific to your code. In the future, please try to debug and figure out the actual underlying error or problem as much as you can before posting on Stack Overflow. Others read these questions as well, so making the questions as applicable to other as possible helps them too.

And remember, errors ion your code just means you're making progress! :)